# Why is creating a uint8 more expensive than a uint256?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

Assume a contract:

```
contract A {

    function b() constant returns (uint8 result) {
      result =1;   
    }
}
```

When I replace `uint8 result` with `uint256 result` then the creation of the contract gets 804 Gas *cheaper*:

```
        gasUsed
uint8     47631  
uint256   46827
```

How does this work?